# Trying to filter model using public_send using name - gives me wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Is `:name` a protected word on Ruby?

Model:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    include Sortable
    include Filterable

    attr_filter :id, :email, :name

    belongs_to :category, class_name: "OrganizationCategory"

    private

    def self.sortable_columns; [:created_at, :name] end

end
```

Filterable class:

```
module Filterable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    
    def self.included(base)
      (class << base; self; end).send(:define_method, "attr_filter") do |*attribs|
        attribs.each do |attrib|
          (class << base; self; end).send(:define_method, attrib) do |*args|
            column = self.arel_table[attrib.to_sym]
            values = args.flatten

            if values.length > 1 
              where(column.lower.in(values.map(&:downcase)))
            elsif values.length == 1 
              where(column.lower.eq("#{values[0].downcase}"))
            end

          end
        end
      end
    end
    
    module ClassMethods
      def filtered(filtering_params)
        results = where(nil)
        filtering_params.each do |key, value|
          results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
        end
        
       results
      end
   end
end
```

I noticed that the only attribute that is giving me this error is `:name`, other attributes work fine. When I try to use an attribute that is not included in `attr_filter` list, I get the expected behaviour, which is, a `No method Error` rescued properly. But name is giving me `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):`

I get the error on this line
`results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?`

Is there any workaround to use `:name` alongside `public_send` since its such a common variable name?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across this, the problem was happening due `:name` already being a method defined by default to any class that inherits from active record. Thus

I came with this workaround, basically, using an constant, so that whenever I come accross a method name I cant use, this code wont break, If I have the word there.

```
module Filterable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    PROTECTED_METHOD_NAMES = [:name]
    
    def self.included(base)
      (class << base; self; end).send(:define_method, "attr_filter") do |*attribs|
        attribs.each do |attrib|

          attrib = protected_word_method_caller(PROTECTED_METHOD_NAMES, attrib)

          (class << base; self; end).send(:define_method, attrib) do |*args|
            attrib.to_s.include? '_protected_word_filter'? attrib = attrib.to_s.split('_')[0] : attrib = attrib
            column = self.arel_table[attrib.to_sym]
            values = args.flatten

            if values.length > 1 
              where(column.lower.in(values.map(&:downcase)))
            elsif values.length == 1 
              where(column.lower.eq("#{values[0].downcase}"))
            end

          end
        end
      end
    end
    
    module ClassMethods
      def filtered(filtering_params)
        results = where(nil)
        filtering_params.each do |key, value|
          key = protected_word_method_caller(PROTECTED_METHOD_NAMES, key)
          results = results.public_send(key, value) if value.present?
        end
        
       results
      end

      private

      def protected_word_method_caller(protected_methods_list, method_name)
        if protected_methods_list.include? method_name.to_sym
          new_method_name = method_name.to_s + '_protected_word_filter'
          method_name = new_method_name.to_sym
        end
        method_name
     end

   end
end
```